# Instance method '-_setWebGLEnabled:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: ios, objective-c, webgl

I checked out this project from git:

https://github.com/atnan/UIWebViewWebGL

after reading the [related article](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios).

The thing works, however Xcode gives me the following warning

```
Instance method '-_setWebGLEnabled:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

at this point:

```
[backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:YES];
```

The project anyway compiles and works, however if I turn ARC on, the warning turns in a error and the project doesn't even compile.
How can I get rid of that warning?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line

```
[backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:YES];
```

by below line

```
[backingWebView performSelector:@selector(_setWebGLEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

You will get rid of this warning.